# Which type of bootstrap to use in bagging?

Tags: bootstrap, panel-data, bagging

Various bootstrap procedures exist (iid bootstrap, block bootstrap, cross sectional bootstrap...). I was wondering which one I should use when bagging classification trees, which I estimate on panel data.

I suspect the iid bootstrap should be ok, as long as I don't use leaded or lagged variables for classification and as long as I can assume there is no cross-sectional dependence in the data?